# How do I change the color of the item in the menu after it is selected in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm creating a dashboard project but I can't find where I change the color after selecting the menu item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqpYK.jpg)
The XML of activity_main_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                android:icon="@drawable/dashboard"
                android:title="@string/menu_dashboard" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                android:icon="@drawable/items"
                android:title="@string/menu_items" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                android:title="@string/menu_shop" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I tried to change the colors via XML but it still doesn't change the color

Comment: please attach image correctly

Answer (score 0):

it uses your primary color of the Theme as background of selected item.